# Can you start an activity as an instance of itself?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a splash screen that creates a new main Activity.
during the Splash screen onCreate method, I am creating a variable as a new Main Activity and a variable as a new instance of my location services.

```
 mMainActivity = new MainActivity();
 mLocationServices = new GooglePlayLocationServicesBC(mMainActivity);
```

Then I init my location services on the splash screen

```
mLocationServices.isGooglePlayAvailable();
mLocationServices.enableLocationUpdates();
```

which sets my Accuracy, Altitude, Bearing, Latitude,Longitude and speed in my Locations BC class. I then want to start my main activity and allow my map to use this data.

Can I use

```
startActivity(mMainActivity);
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: * I have tried it. thats psyudo code for what I want to do which is start the main activity as an instance of itself which I have already set on my splash screen.

Comment: `mMainActivity = new MainActivity();` you can't do that.

Comment: Understood, can you explain why? Maybe offer another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot call `new` for an `Activity`.  The only way that they can be created is by calling `Context.startActivity()` or `Context.startActivityForResult()`.